# Finding a substring from a variable string length using VB in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an Access DB with a few tables, one of which has a column of address. These addresses all begin with a building name and are followed by city information. They are all separated by commas.

I am looking for a way in the VB code to take this field and separate it into two fields, with everything left of the first comma in one field and everything right of the first comma in the other.

I've tried variations on the following:

```
currentBuildingName = currentBuildingAddress.Substring(0, currentBuildingAddress.IndexOf(","))
currentCity = currentBuildingAddress.Substring(currentBuildingAddress.IndexOf(","), 1)
```

But with no success. I've also tried looking at the left() and right() functions, but they require you to specify the integer location of where the split should occur, which is variable.

Any advice folks? How can I split a string based on the first comma, with everything to the left in one field and everything to the right in another field, in MS Access 2010?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `InStr()` function, `InStr("expression_to_search", "search_string")`. It returns the starting position of the string you're searching for or zero if it doesn't find it. Once you've got the position of the comma you can use `Right()` and `Left()` to parse the string. For more details see

[InStr Function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/instr-function-HA001228857.aspx).

Comment: Yeah this is the way to go. I'll mark this as accepted, but post my end result as a separate answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @OTTA for the guidance. This was my final answer:

```
startingPosition = InStr(currentBuildingAddress, ",")

currentBuildingName = Left(currentBuildingAddress, (startingPosition))
currentCity = Right(currentBuildingAddress, Len(currentBuildingAddress) - startingPosition)
```

Nice and simple.